# products are not displaying on front end home page in magento 1.7.0

Tags: php, magento

first I had truncated `catalog_product_entity` table and then I imported 2000 products and it get imported successfully. Then, I cleared all cache and re-indexed all data But whenever I come to home page It always showing me the same error/information message " There are no products matching the selection."

Comment: Can you try to reindex everything in System -> Index Management -> (Select all) -> Reindex Data

Comment: yes everything I re-indexed

Comment: can u please tell me all product is enabled???

Comment: How did you load your product in home page ..? If you load by category id means check that category have any product with itself..

Comment: also check flat table is enabled or not...

Comment: how to check whether flat table is enable or not?

Comment: on home page there is one block for new products, one slider for features peoducts, one is for most viewed products and all are fetching products from all categories

Comment: Try out this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838596/how-to-remove-all-catalog-products-in-magento it will help you with removing all product form catalog